# Using missing within initialize method of a reference class

Tags: r, arguments, reference-class

I'm looking to create a generator function for a dummy reference class that would create empty objects of correct classes if arguments are not given.

## Code

```
#' Class SummaryData
#'
#' @description Odd class facilitating creation of data frame with
#'   summary information attached.
#'
#' @slot data data.frame.
#' @slot summary_columns character.
#' @slot info character.
#'
#' @return A SummaryData Class
#' @import methods
#' @exportClass SummaryData
#'
setClass(
    Class = "SummaryData",
    slots = list(
        data = "data.frame",
        summary_columns = "character",
        info = "character"
    )
)

#' Constructor method of SummaryData.
#'
#' @name SummaryData
#' @rdname SummaryData-class
setMethod("initialize", "SummaryData", function(.Object,
                                           data = "data.frame",
                                           summary_columns = "character",
                                           info = "character",
                                           ...)
{
    if (missing(data)) {
        data <- data.frame()
    }
    if (missing(summary_columns)) {
        summary_columns <- character()
    }
    if (missing(comment(info))) {
        info <- character()
    }

    validObject(.Object)
    return(.Object)
})

#' Wrapper function SummaryData.
#'
#' @name SummaryData
#' @rdname SummaryData-class
#' @export
SummaryData <- function(...) new("SummaryData", ...)
```

## Problem

```
SummaryData(data = mtcars, summary_columns = c("cyl", "mpg"), info = "Cars data")
```

Gives this error:

> Error in missing(comment(info)) : invalid use of 'missing'
>    SummaryData(data = mtcars, summary_columns = c("cyl", "mpg"))
>    Error in missing(comment(info)) : invalid use of 'missing'

## Desired results

The second call should create `SummaryData` object with empty `info` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `missing("data")` or `do.call(missing, list("data"))` instead of `missing(data)`. They both should work.

However, you cannot use it with `comment(info)`, since `missing` only accepts argument names, but `comment` will rather return `NULL`. As long as the argument is supplied to a function call, it will not be missed, I guess. So, you'll need to check the argument `info` first and then do whatever you want.

Hope this helps.